# How to set dynamic pivots for rotate animation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-animation

I have an image. I need it to rotate by a small angle pivoted on its lower left corner. This animation works when i tap screen. The image appears there and rotates.  But for different positions , the pivot is constant. How can i dynamically set pivot for each case programmatically?

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:toDegrees="10"/>
</set>
```

Is there any way we give the pivots value with the value we `getX()` and `getY()` ?

Comment: How are you doing the rotation animation?  Depending on what you're using to do that, you'll get different answers.  If you're doing it by matrix, you can translate origin to the point you want as the pivot before applying the rotation matrix.

Comment: I haven't tried using matrix.  Now i will do that. I have used the xml to do rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.  done it by doing like this

```
var screenH=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
var screenH=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels

var x= ("x value of your pivot)/screenW

var y= ("y value of your pivot)/screenH

var rotateAnim=RotateAnimation(0.0f , 20.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT , x , 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT , y)

rotateAnim.setDuration(1000)
rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true)

view.startAnimation(rotateAnim)
```